# Show Snackbar in any part of app

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app and I need to determine internet connection loss in any part of the app I am in and 
show it with a `SnackBar` "only once in the app". I use a `Broadcast Receiver` to determine this. But the problem is if I in `Application.java`, I do not have 
view to tell snackbar. If I implement in `SubActivity` or `SubFragment`, I need to implement in each `Activity` or `Fragment` extending 
these `SubActivity` or `SubFragment` and `SnackBar` pop-up in each `Activity` or `fragment` is annoying. If I do it with `Service`, again I need to tell each `Activity` and `Fragment` from service.
How do I do this?

Comment: Can you please add the Java code, and one more thing if there is no interface in `Application.java` why u showing snackbar. ?

Comment: how did u finally implement it ? I am looking for same.